# How to check the vertex/edge/polygon count of one or more object?

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices, edges, polycount

Is there a way to check the selected object(s) vertex/edge/polygon count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Script to print stats to system console**

Script prints the stats of selected mesh object to system console.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

sumfaces = []
for o in context.selected_objects:
    if o.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    me = o.data
    verts = len(me.vertices)
    edges = len(me.edges)
    faces = len(me.polygons)
    sumfaces.append(faces)
    print("%s: verts:%d edges:%d polys %d"
            % (o.name, verts, edges, faces))

print("total polys %d" % sum(sumfaces))
```

Sample output.

```
Cube: verts:8 edges:12 polys 6
Suzanne: verts:507 edges:1005 polys 500

total polys 506
```

Answer (score 0):

The info area shows these numbers.

Select an object -> go into edit mode -> select all -> view the numbers on the top bar (default setup).

For **2.8+**: This information is now disabled by default but can be enabled by right clicking on the "Status Bar" at the bottom of the window, as described here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/status_bar.html

Comment: guess this changed since 2.8 ? :/